# Presenting UIViewController in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I have recently started with ios development. So currently I have a requirement to present a QR scanner view when a view is clicked. I came through one library https://github.com/twostraws/CodeScanner.  but it doesn't work.

I have also the QR code implementation

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class QRCode: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.ean8, .ean13, .pdf417]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func failed() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
        captureSession = nil
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
//func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }


}
```

but I am not able to use this inside a class which inherits `UIView`

The class definition in which I am trying to use the `QRCode` class

`class A: UIView`

I have recently started with ios. Any help would be great

Comment: Why are you trying to launch from a UIView?  Why not launch from the view's view controller?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear so there is a view controller A  which presents UIview B but my requirement is inside view B have to add the above QRCode controller to present  scanner but can't find any way to do so

Comment: No, you were clear.  You should do it from the view's hosting view controller, not the view itself. You can still get exactly the same workflow.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to present a view controller from a presented view controller you can do the following

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func presentPressed(sender: Any) {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let presentedVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presentedViewController")
        present(presentedVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class presentedViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func presentQRVCPressed(sender: Any) {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let qrVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QRViewController")
        present(qrVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class QRViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]

otherwise if you want to present a view controller when clicking inside a view, do the following

```
protocol yourCustomViewDelegate: class {
    func presentQRPressed()
}

class yourCustomView: UIView {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    weak var delegate: yourCustomViewDelegate?
    
    @IBAction func presentQRButton(sender: Any) {
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.presentQRPressed()
        }
    }
}

class yourViewController: UIViewController, yourCustomViewDelegate {
    func presentQRPressed() {
        present(yourQRVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```